# Application Server Administration Service Timer Job doesn't finish or fail

Tags: 2013, timer-jobs

Lately the Application Server Administration Service Timer Job does not complete on one WFE and runs long on the other WFE.  Since it does not fail I do not see an error logged.  What could cause this job to run, but not complete or fail?

Thanks

Comment: can you make sure SharePoint Admin services is running on both WFE...from Services console.

Comment: The SharePoint Admin service is running on both WFE servers. Thanks

Comment: did you see any error in the Event log, becuase if it is running long then it will cause a problem for farm.

Comment: how long it is running?

Comment: Three hours on one WFE and one on the second WFE.  They have run longer, but I restarted the SharePoint Timer Service after making some changes that I thought would help this issue.

Comment: I recently added two new content databases to my farm, could there be some configuration that I missed that would cause this issue?

Comment: try to restart the SharePoint admin service, that is which execute the "Application Server Administration Service Timer Job". after restarting then test it

Comment: Thanks for the tip, should I do this on all SP servers, WFEs, or the APP server this is happening on?

Comment: for smooth operation, i would recycle it on all servers in farm. please share the result if it solve the problem.

Comment: I recycled the service on all servers, but the job is still running.  Should I recycle the Timer Service again?  Tried to move this to a chat but this wouldn't let me.  Thanks

Comment: yes try to recycle timer service after that..also check the event log for any clue

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work either.  I see nothing in the event viewers to help me with this either.  I appreciate you trying to help me out though.  I will be rebooting the server tonight to see if that helps.  Thanks again...

Comment: can you see if any other timer services is running same time, may be a deadlock...also check if server can access the internet.

Comment: No other services running at same time, and server have access to the internet.  frustrating...

Comment: A reboot of the servers fixed the issue, but still don't have initial cause.  Thanks

Comment: great, basically the job stuck which should cleared while recycling the Admin service / timer service but in worst condition you need to reboot. glad finally done.